# How to dynamicly add an option via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an option via JavaScript when IE load the page. I searched it in google, but still cannot get the resolution.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add(){
            var c = document.getElementById("number");
            var e = document.createElement("option");
            e.setAttribute("value", "1");
            e.appendChild(document.createTextNode("two");
            c.appendChild(e);
        }
    </script>
<body onload="add()">
    <form action="" method="post">
        favirate city:
        <select id="number">
            <option value="0">one</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `new Option()` instead of `document.createElement("option")`

Comment: Obligatory: have you checked the error console and the JS debugger?

Comment: You have a missing `)` in this line: `e.appendChild(document.createTextNode("two");`

Comment: You're also missing a closing parenthesis after `document.createTextNode` - oooops, 19 secs @Ian :P

Comment: @LightStyle That's not where the problem is. (The `Option` thing. The missing paren is the issue.)

Comment: @LightStyle `new Option()` shouldn't have an effect

Comment: @millimoose, mine was just a suggestion ;)

Comment: @LightStyle I'm not a fan of potentially sending askers on a wild goose chase based on hunches that could easily be verified.

Comment: Anyway, voting to close because the OP did zero diagnosis all-in-all, and consequently hasn't provided a valid code sample demonstrating the issue. SO is not a human compiler service.

Comment: Even with `new Option` the only issue seems to be the missing `)`. Anyway, IMHO, it's more readable, and should be used since it is there for a reason.

Comment: By the way, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/kXLSq/

Comment: @LightStyle I'd rather be consistent and always use `document.createElement`. Everyone has their own reasons for using something. If you provided a reason for why it would **fix** the problem, or why you suggested that, in the **first place**, we probably wouldn't have questioned you as badly

Comment: @Ian: simply because its constructor helps avoiding `textNodes` and *stupid* typos like the OP's one. In this case a simple `new Option('two', '1')` would have fixed the issue, saving a line of code. That's not superfluous, not at all at least.

Comment: *cough* bikeshed argument *cough*

Comment: But at least I provided one, on your contrary ;)

Comment: @LightStyle Like I said, my point is consistency. Yours is readability. I never said anything about being superfluous. And I never argued against it...just that it wouldn't fix anything. And that code would **not** have fixed the problem, because it's unrelated to the line without the `)`. Exchanging `new Option` and `document.createElement("option")` makes no difference. And I'm sorry, but `var opt = document.createElement("option"); opt.text = "text"; opt.value = "value";` is much more **readable** to me

Comment: The code would have become this: `var c = document.getElementById("number"); var e = new Option('two', '1'); c.appendChild(e);` the line with the textnode isn't there anymore. It is not touched, it is directly removed. Anyway, I think it's a matter of different points of view. I obviously accept it, since you're not wrong. My intention was only to help, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @LightStyle Again, I understand. My only opposition was that it would "fix" anything like you said. Other than that, I completely agree it's a matter of viewpoint, that's why I wasn't trying to argue one way or the other outside of that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code... I updated little bit

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add(){
            var c = document.getElementById("number");
            var lastVal = Number(c.lastChild.value) + 1;
            var e = document.createElement("option");
            e.setAttribute("value", lastVal);
            e.appendChild(document.createTextNode("two"));
            c.appendChild(e);
        }
    </script>
<body onload="add()">
    <form action="" method="post">
        favirate city:
        <select id="number">
            <option value="0">one</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var option = new Option('myText', 'val');
var select = document.getElementById("number");
select.appendChild(option);
```